# Why I need to click 2 times on link to change the location

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have moved all routes to a module

main_app.js

```
app.module('main_app', ['sub_module])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$location', function ($r, $l) {
        $r.go = function (path) {
            $l.path(path);
        };
    }])
```

sub_module.js

```
angular.module('sub_module', ['ngRoute' ,'ngResource'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/company', {
                controller: 'CompanyController',
                templateUrl: '/company/index.html'
            })
        ;
    }])
```

when some template i pul a `<a href="#" data-ng-click="go('/company')">Company</a>` and clic the link i need clic two times, the question is WHY?

Comment: event now is now works the path nevers changes :(

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure but you can try this:

```
<a href="" data-ng-click="go('/company')">Company</a>
```